# Changing a barchart edge color after plotting it

Tags: python

I am using Python with `matlibplot` to plot a barchart.
Originally I want no edgecolour for the abrs and so when I plot, I use:

```
h = plt.bar(x, y, width, edgecolor="none")
```

Later on, if a condition is met, I want to change the edge colour to e.g. black.

Is there away I can do it using the handle `h`? Something like `h.setEdgecolour("black")`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer off another forum that geared just for python (python-forum.org)

```
plt.setp(h,edgecolor = "black")
```